# Symfony - display file stored outside public

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there a possibility to display file in twig template when the the file is not stored inside public directory? Like call controller which would return binary response for requested file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to embed a controller response into a twig template you can use the `render` function.

```
{{ render(path('latest_articles', {max: 3})) }}

or

{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\BlogController::recentArticles', {max: 3})) }}
```

Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers